# Fetching Record Pattern From Database

Tags: php, mysql, pattern-matching

I have a table like this in my database.

```
|   id   |   yes_answer   |   no_answer  |
|   a01  |      a05       |     a04      |
|   a03  |      a16       |     a32      |
|   a04  |      c01       |     a05      |
|   a05  |      a06       |     c06      |
|   a06  |      a08       |     a09      |
|   a08  |      c03       |     a09      |
|   a09  |      a03       |              |
|   a16  |      a33       |     a02      |
|   a32  |      c04       |     a16      |
|   a33  |      c05       |              |
```

As An Explanation : 
1.`id` column represent an id of question. it is linked to another table on my database. 
2.`yes_answer` column represent the next question (like `a01`) or conclusion (like `c04`) you get when you answer the question represented by `id` column with `yes` or `TRUE` or `1` value.
3.`no_answer` is generally the same as `yes_answer column` except that you get it when you answer question represented by `id` column with `no`, `FALSE`, `0` value.
4. Every `id`, `yes_answer`, `no_answer` is connected each other. The Result is A Pattern. When you Want to find a path that lead to answer `c01` it will be like `c05` -> `a33`,`a16`,`a32`,`a03`,`a09`,`a06`,`a05`,`a01`.

And Here I am Trying To Bactrack The Pattern From `answer` column that marked with `c` like `c01` or `c02` like above. And I've been able to bactrack only the beginning value of it Like (`c05` -> `a33`) and the rest is blank.

Here is My Code

```
$sqlQueryYes="SELECT * FROM tbl_path_inference WHERE yes_answer='c05'";
$execQueryYes=mysql_query($sqlQueryYes);<br />
$queryStatus=mysql_num_rows($execQueyYes); //Getting Query Status<br />
if($queryStatus == 1) {
    $getDataYes=mysql_fetch_array($execQueryYes);
    $ansPath=$ansPath." ".$getDataYes['id'];
} else { // if cant find answer on column yes_answer try on no_answer
    $sqlQueryNo="SELECT * FROM tbl_path_inference WHERE no_answer='c05'";
    $execQueryNo=mysql_query($sqlQueryNo);
    $getDataNo=mysql_fetch_array($execQueryNo);
    $ansPath=$ansPath." ".$getDataNo;
}
```

Anyone Have Solution On It. Im Still working It Now.

Comment: Here's a useful site: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: I Have Fix It. There Is My Example Code

Comment: Please put that answer in an answer block below as a self-answer, ok?

Comment: Its Not An Answer Drew. My Code Can Only Fetch Only One Path. Not A Full Path Like When i Try To Find A Path For `c05`, i can only fetch `a33`. Thats It. Only One Path.

Comment: Why do you capitalize every word like that? It's really hard to read. Is it a stupid mobile device?

Comment: It looks like you haven't made any attempt to solve the problem yourself. You just fetch one row, you need to keep doing it in a loop, using the result of the first query in the `WHERE` clause of the next one.

Comment: @AdityaChristianto I thought you solved it. I was just flying thru questions.

Comment: The problem is i dont know until when i should loop it. Could i Just count the table row, and set the limiting variable with the sum of table row?